# Is it possible to configure custom queries in mqsql module of metricbeat

Tags: metricbeat

Is it possible to configure custom queries in mqsql module of metricbeat. I want to get the count of records in a particular table using metricbeat mysql module.

If this is not possible, is there a way to create a new metricset in mysql metricbeat module or create a custom module in metricbeat to do this? Anyone have any links that can help me in creating the custom module?

Comment: https://help.datadoghq.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000133723-How-to-collect-metrics-from-custom-MySQL-queries

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/devguide/current/metricbeat-developer-guide.html

Comment: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/execute-a-custom-sql-query-using-mysql-metricbeat-module

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/devguide/current/compiling-and-running.html

Comment: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-package-metricbeat-code/127597

Comment: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/change-the-time-interval-of-mysql-modules-status-metricset/130406